# How do I get my radio buttons to set data in a text field?

Tags: java, jradiobutton

Can't get these radio buttons to work. I'd like them to set two text fields upon choosing one button. What am I missing?

Also, why isn't my code posting to this forum correctly?

```
//import all needed functionality
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.*;
```

Comment: Regarding why your code is not formatted properly: Here's how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Check at the assignation of the JTextFields I think what you want to do is: years.setText(String.valueOf(7)); and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Radio Buttons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). I don't see where you are adding an ActionListener to the buttons.